# Can app store video previews be seen across multiple device sizes?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes

I'm wondering if an app store video preview could be seen across multiple device sizes, or whether a different video is really required for each device size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need a different video for each screen size. Resizing the video for the different screen size will also get rejected by apple.

Source `Experience`

Answer (score 0):

You may only submit a single set of app previews (videos) designed for iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad in one language localization.

Just like screenshots, each app preview (video) is device-specific and requires an iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch with a 4-inch Retina display to view or submit.

Refrence - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-previews/